# Show without last commas on categories

Tags: php, mysql, show

I have this code:

```
<?
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
      $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
        while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
            print $cat2['name_cat'];
    }

   }

?>
```

Now show categories in this:   ActionsComedyMystery and i want to show Actions,Comedy,Mystery (with no commas at end)

Comment: Please don't build new applications with `mysql_query`. You should be using PDO or `mysqli` to avoid **severe** [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) like you have in this example.

Comment: And learn about table joins... you can do this in 1 db query rather than 1+n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the categories into an array and concat them with the `implode()` function.

```
$result = implode(",", $items);
```

With your example:

```
<?
$items = Array();

$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
  $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
  while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
    $items[] = $cat2['name_cat'];
  }
}

echo implode(",", $items);
?>
```

**Edit:** With Mysqli and Join:

```
<?
$db = @new mysqli( 'host', 'user', 'pass', 'database' );

$items = Array();

$kate = $db->query("select movies_cat.category_id, categories.name_cat from movies_cat, categories where movies_cat.category_id = categories.name_cat AND WHERE movie_id='$ids'");
while($cat = $kate->fetch_array($kate)){
    $items[] = $kate['name_cat'];
}

echo implode(",", $items);
?>
```

Comment: please insert you in a code function implode! i don't know! thanks

Comment: The `implode()` function is built into php by default.

Comment: `implode()` is a PHP function.  Please read the manual and become familiar with the native functions.

Comment: i marked! thanks again! Man how to make code with join table? is better with join ? please update my code with table join! thanks!

Comment: Join is better as only one query has to be executed in this example. I updated the code with join and mysqli.

Comment: dates of db i have in config.php what type in $db = @new mysqli( 'host', 'user', 'pass', 'database' );  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it saving the categories to a var then at end echoing that variable omitting the last character, like this:

```
$out = '';
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
      $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
        while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
            $out .= $cat2['name_cat'] . ',';
    }

   }

echo substr($out,0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable first. Use PDO instead of mysql_query. Try to optimize your logic.

```
$category = ""
```

Now,

```
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
    $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
    while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
        $category .= $cat2['name_cat'].",";
   }

 }

echo substr_replace($category ,"",-1);
```